# What is the significance of the change in tense from "rise" to "measure" in Revelation 11:1?

Tags: greek

> Then I was given a measuring rod like a staff, and I was told, “Rise and measure the temple of God and the altar and those who worship there, (Revelation 11:1 ESV)
>
> καὶ ἐδόθη μοι κάλαμος ὅμοιος ῥάβδῳ λέγων **ἔγειρε καὶ μέτρησον** τὸν ναὸν τοῦ θεοῦ καὶ τὸ θυσιαστήριον καὶ τοὺς προσκυνοῦντας ἐν αὐτῷ

After receiving an instrument, John is told to "rise and measure..." Both verbs are imperative active. However, rise is in the present tense and measure is in the aorist.

What is the significance of "measure" in the aorist tense relative to the command to "rise" in the present tense?

Comment: I checked your verb information and Bagster's Analytical Lexicon agrees with you. I hope someone may have an answer to the aorist use in the second verb.

Answer (score 1):

In class at Moody, Dr. Ron Saur would often highlight verbs that oddly appeared in the aorist tense, including the aorist imperative. He often explained the difference of ***present*** vs ***aorist***:

- **Present**: ongoing, continuous action — continuing persistently and not ending
- **Aorist**: completed, punctiliar action — over and done with

After two years of this, four days a week, with Bible exegesis examples at the beginning of every class, I would feel like a dunce in class if my answer did not include:

> *John was commanded to rise and stay standing and keep measuring until the measurements were complete and thoroughly finished.*

The exegetical meaning of that would be:

> God wanted John to stay up and do the great work until it was finished. Once measured, we have the absolute, complete, total information about the measurements of New Jerusalem. There were no measurements in Revelation that were incomplete because the measurements were in the completed aorist and the work was done in the continuous, ongoing work of staying on his feet until the job was done.

---

This isn't part of the text specifically, but Saur would often go on to say something like...

*We need to continue in our tasks until they are completed. The confident certainty of knowing that our information is accurate depends on our ongoing commitment to finish what we are assigned. Just as much, we can depend on God's Word because the measurements were full and complete, persistently done, even until the last book of the Bible.*

---

That's the best I have. Hope it helps.

Comment: Much appreciated. Thank you. (+1).

Comment: Since the second action is the aorist (in the past), should we understand John had previously measured? In other words, John is to resume something he had previously begun essentially, "Rise and finish measuring" or perhaps again measure?

Comment: From my understanding from class, absolutely not. The aorist is much more than "past", it is "punctiliar, completed". It might be comparable to "get it done." Saur often talked about aorist with imperative to say that the emphasis was on the completion of the action, no implication that it was an event from the past.